# Bluetooth Server на Android

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, клиент-сервер

Хочу попробовать создать клиент-сервер на android по bluetooth, но так нигде не смог найти точную информацию сколько одновременно android устройств(клиентов) я могу подключить к одному(серверу).

Answer (score 1):

Bluetooth-канал способен соединить между собой два устройства. То, которое инициирует соединение и работает как ведущее (Master) может взаимодействовать максимум с семью зависимыми (Slave). Например, сотовый телефон в качестве ведущего устройства может производить синхронизацию данных с компьютером и одновременно осуществлять отправку фотографий на Bluetooth-принтер. Правда, компьютер как ведомое устройство в такой иерархии не сможет получить доступ к принтеру, хотя они и находятся в одной сети: ему понадобится установить новое соединение с принтером в качестве Master-устройства.

Сеть WLAN может включать в себя 25–30 устройств. Для Bluetooth максимум – 8. Однако при этом в сети Bluetooth могут одновременно находиться более 200 «пассивных» устройств, каждое из них будет активировано в течение нескольких миллисекунд, если одно из активных Slave-устройств освободит соединение и поступит запрос от Master-устройства.

Bluetooth использует более узкие частотные коридоры, и переход от одного канала к другому при наличии соединения происходит с частотой 1600 раз в секунду. Эта скачкообразная смена частоты делает Bluetooth менее чувствительным к внешним воздействиям, так как при возникновении помех соединение будет находиться на «критической» частоте лишь незначительное время. Благодаря этому в непосредственной близости друг от друга могут работать до 10 Bluetooth-сетей.

http://www.pccar.ru/showthread.php?t=14098